# Replacing XPath string in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, sh

everybody. 
I need help with the following matter.
I have an XSL file with XPath which correspond to an XML file with UBL 2.0 standard and I need the XPath to fit UBL 2.1 standard.

The number of Files which need the change is too numerous, for that reason I'm trying to use the sed command to replace the XPath in each file. I have tried the next command:

```
sed -i 's/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID"\/>/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cac:Party\/cac:PartyIdentification\/cbc:ID"\/>/g' path/to/file
```

The XPath contains characters that need to be escaped, so my doubt is if I will have no problems with the replacement of the paths with the current structure of the command

Answer (score 1):

Don't work on XML with regular expressions.

Since XSLT is XML itself, you can use XSLT to edit it. Start with the identity transform and add a specific template for the attribute you want to modify.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:apply-templates/@select[
      . = '/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID'
    ]">
        <xsl:attribute name="select">
            <xsl:text>/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```